# How to get substring of substring from xml node using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

How to get  substring of substring from xml node using xslt?

e.g.

input:

```
<node>This Is W3 School</node>
```

output:

```
<node>TIWS</node>
```

Here, I want to get first letter of each substring separated by space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, for all your answers.
As I am using xslt versio: 1.0 ,I have write substring functions to get desired output.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="node">
      <node1>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(substring-before(normalize-space(substring-after(//node,'')),' '),1,1)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(substring-after(normalize-space(substring-after(//node,'')),' '),1,1)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(substring-before(normalize-space(substring-after(normalize-space(substring-after(//node,' ')),' ')),' '),1,1)"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(substring-after(normalize-space(substring-after(normalize-space(substring-after(//node,' ')),' ')),' '),1,1)"/>
    </node1>
    </xsl:template>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please let me know if I can reduce the code in same xslt version 1.0

Comment: Please see my answer below for an XSLT 1.0 alternative that can handle more than one `node` element in the document and also handles more than 5 substrings.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use `tokenize(., ' ')` in the context of the `node` element to get a sequence of the strings, then you can use the `substring` function for the first letter e.g. in XSLT 3 `tokenize(., ' ')!substring(., 1, 1)` or in XSLT 2 `for $token in tokenize(., ' ') return substring($token, 1, 1)`.

Then output the result with `xsl:value-of` e.g. in XSLT 3

```
  <xsl:template match="node">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(., ' ')!substring(., 1, 1)" separator=""/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKvY

or in XSLT 2 with

```
  <xsl:template match="node">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="for $token in tokenize(., ' ') return substring($token, 1, 1)" separator=""/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use [`fn:replace()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-replace) with a regex and a capture group:

```
fn:replace("This Is W3 School", "([A-Z])\w+\s?", "$1")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're stuck with XSLT 1.0 you could use a recursive template call to process the string.

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<doc>
    <node>This Is W3 School</node>
    <node>One Two Three Four Five Six</node>
    <node>Hello </node>
    <node>      X   Y   Z      </node>
    <node/>    
</doc>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="node">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:call-template name="first_letters"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="first_letters">
    <xsl:param name="input" select="normalize-space()"/>
    <xsl:variable name="remaining" select="substring-after($input,' ')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring($input,1,1)"/>
    <xsl:if test="$input">
      <xsl:call-template name="first_letters">
        <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$remaining"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<doc>
   <node>TIWS</node>
   <node>OTTFFS</node>
   <node>H</node>
   <node>XYZ</node>
   <node/>
</doc>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKw1

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="node">
       <xsl:variable name="s" select="tokenize(.,' ')"/>

    <xsl:element name="node">
        <xsl:for-each select="$s">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,1)"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
First of all tokenize the string then use substring for your desire output
```